# How to view and delete zip files and folder in directory

Tags: php

I am trying to get the list of all the zip files in my particular directory for ex.

```
C:/xampp/htdocs
```

But most important thing is that I would like to get all the zip file from all the folders means it should check in all the sub folders.

After getting all the zip file, I would like to delete zip file on click of delete button.

I have tried following example by googling but not working. I have also tried other solution also.

```
foreach (glob("*.zip") as $filename) {
 if(unlink($filename))
        echo "success" ;
 else
        echo "Failure"
}
```

OR

```
  <?php 
function list_zipfiles($mydirectory) {

    // directory we want to scan
    $dircontents = scandir('c:/xampp/htdocs');

    // list the contents
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($dircontents as $file) {
        $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($extension == 'zip') {
            echo "<li>$file </li>";
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will list all the zip files into the particular directory.

For testing you can create test folder and add some inner folder into it and put zip files. So that it will not take long to scan and display all the files.

```
<?php

$mydirectory    = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test';


// create recursive directory iterator for zip folder
$directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($mydirectory); 
// required to iterate through results using foreach
$recursive_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator);
// filter only .zip files
$regex_iterator = new RegexIterator($recursive_iterator, '/^.*\.zip$/',
                          RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

// iterate through results
foreach($regex_iterator as $file_info) {
    var_dump($file_info);
}
```

---

> **To remove file**

use **unlink()** function to remove the files. On click of particular link should take you to the php page where you can get the file name and remove it.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

        if (!empty($_POST['zip_file'])) {
            if (!unlink($_POST['zip_file']))
            {
               echo ("file cannot be deleted due to an error");
            }
            else
            {
               echo ("file has been deleted");
            }
        }
        header('location:zip_delete_demo.php');
        die();
    }

?>

    <html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="zip_form" id="zip_form">
        <?php
        $mydirectory    = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\php_demo';
        $directory_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($mydirectory); 
        $recursive_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator);
        $regex_iterator = new RegexIterator($recursive_iterator, '/^.*\.zip$/',RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

        foreach($regex_iterator as $file_info) {
            echo '<a class="btn_delete_zip" href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="'.$file_info[0].'">'.$file_info[0].'</a><br/>';
?>

  <?php          
        }

        ?>

        </form>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click','.btn_delete_zip',function(){
                var zip_file = jQuery(this).data('href');

                var input = $("<input>")
               .attr("name", "zip_file")
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .val(zip_file);

                $('#zip_form').append(input);
                $('#zip_form').submit();


            });
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

> **Notes**

Please increase the maximum execution time in php.ini file.
Please don't test your code by putting any exist or die function. It will list out only single file.